# Assigning domain name to host on Route 53 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I'm deploying my first app on EC2. I have a domain name registered, lets call it example.com. My ec2 instance has a public ip, lets say, 100.100.100.100. When I got the EC2 instance, I already have a wordpress site installed on it (the blog for my app - blog.example.com). Hitting the public ip directly goes to the blog.

My app is running on the 4000 port of this EC2 instance. I want to assign the example.com domain to this.

I'm using AWS Route 53 for the DNS. I'm clicking on `create a record set`, where I give the name - www.example.com to the value 100.100.100.100:4000. The type is an `IP-v4`. However, when I try to assign this, I get the error below:

`The record set could not be saved because:
- The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format.`

It's because I've specified the port of the ip in the value. How do I get example.co to point to this app on 100.100.100.100:4000? Thank you for all the help in advance!

Comment: You can't assign ports via DNS.

Comment: Ohh, I did not know that. Thanks! I should google this a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Route53 is a global Domain Name Service (DNS).

DNS services are used to **resolve DNS names** (eg `example.com`) to an IP address (eg `100.100.100.100`). However, **DNS servers do not point to ports on a machine** (eg port `4000`).

Therefore, to refer to `100.100.100.100:4000`, you would use `example.com:4000`.

Comment: Thank you John, I'm new to programming and your answer greatly helps! Is it possible to somehow have example.com point to the 4000 port, or do I need to set up a new instance?

Comment: Domain names just return an IP address, which belongs to the machine as a whole. When you connect to a machine, you need a name or IP address AND a port. They are completely separate concepts. By default, web browsers go to port 80 for HTTP and port 443 for HTTPS. So, no, it is not possible to have a domain name point to a port -- they point to machines.